# Switch from Asp.net Rc1 to Rtm throws exception that i dont understand

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, rtm

I made a new Project in Rtm and transferred then my code to that project. I got it so far that I don’t get any errors in VS. When I try to start the IIS I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

It happens when the dbcontext is created for IServiceCollection.

Any idea what could cause it?

Sorry that I’m not posting any code but I don’t even know where to start because I don’t understand the error. If you want to see any code just ask.

Comment: Seems like you have not configured your application for IIS. Make sure that you have `Program.cs` class exactly configured the way it is required in RTM. Try to run it on Kestrel before.

Comment: I get the same exception under Kerstel :(.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that some 3rd-party libraries that you use are not upgraded/compatible to RTM. Check all you non-microsoft dependencies in `project.json`
2. Also, read this upgrade guide carefully: [Migrating from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html)